# Run `dotnet test` equivalent with pure Mono

Tags: f#, mono

I'm trying F# and have a tiny project where I could run `dotnet test`, but I wanted to do it without installing any non-free software from Microsoft.

Alternatives to using `dotnet` all seem to use pretty complex commands like:

```
$ mono packages/xunit.runner.console.2.0.0/tools/xunit.console.exe build/test/CommandLine.Tests.dll
```

Being a complete newcomer, I have zero hint how those might need tweaking to work in my case.

My `HelloWorld.fsproj` contains:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="HelloWorld.fs" />
    <Compile Include="HelloWorldTests.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="FsUnit.xUnit" Version="4.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Note that for the RMS-ish definition of "free", the project is also installing non-free software via packages. I think that pretty much by definition, you can't do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @LexLi I can't explain why .NET Core is non free, as it is under the MIT license. I can, however, explain that I didn't know there was a difference between .Net Framework (non-free) and .NET Core (MIT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Mono and .NET core have an MIT license.   There's no reason you should not use .NET core nowadays, specially with .NET core 5 which is aiming at unifying the capabilities of .NET core and Mono.

On another note, there's an unnecessary line in your project code if you're not using Visual Studio (commercial license).

```
 <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still interested in doing this, here's how I've done it in the past with C#: create a new target named "test" that you can invoke from MSBuild (works on Windows w/ Microsoft .NET Framework, or cross-platform with Mono). Should translate over to F# just fine.

CSPROJ:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Test" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="$(XunitConsole472Path) &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Unit test:

```cs
using Xunit;

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.True(false);
    }
}
```

Command line:

```
  sh$ msbuild /v:minimal /t:restore
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.1 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.

  sh$ msbuild /v:minimal /t:test
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.10.1 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  mono-command-line -> /home/bradwilson/dev/repro/mono-command-line/bin/Debug/net472/mono-command-line.dll
  ﻿xUnit.net Console Runner v2.5.0+92f31c4c3a (64-bit .NET Framework 4.7.2, runtime: 4.0.30319.42000)
    Discovering: mono-command-line
    Discovered:  mono-command-line
    Starting:    mono-command-line
  ﻿    UnitTest1.Test1 [FAIL]
        Assert.True() Failure
        Expected: True
        Actual:   False
        Stack Trace:
            at UnitTest1.Test1 () [0x00001] in <95f79fdc5f284dbf9719f6544e480f5a>:0
            at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <d636f104d58046fd9b195699bcb1a744>:0
    Finished:    mono-command-line
  === TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
     mono-command-line  Total: 1, Errors: 0, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0, Time: 0.054s
/home/bradwilson/dev/repro/mono-command-line/mono-command-line.csproj(8,5): error MSB3073: The command "mono /home/bradwilson/.nuget/packages/xunit.runner.console/2.5.0/build/../tools/net472/xunit.console.exe "/home/bradwilson/dev/repro/mono-command-line/bin/Debug/net472/mono-command-line.dll"" exited with code 1.
```